# LSTM with Numpy, can't find a definitive algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am doing LSTM from scratch and am following this guide, but the loss is not decreasing but increasing. This is the best guide I have found thus far but that is not saying much as even this one is incomplete. Aside from spotting the problem specific to my code I would appreciate any sources showing the full sequence of a LSTM.

https://wiseodd.github.io/techblog/2016/08/12/lstm-backprop/

Model definition:

```
import numpy as np


H = 128 # Number of LSTM layer's neurons
D = ... # Number of input dimension == number of items in vocabulary
Z = H + D # Because we will concatenate LSTM state with the input

model = dict(
    Wf=np.random.randn(Z, H) / np.sqrt(Z / 2.),
    Wi=np.random.randn(Z, H) / np.sqrt(Z / 2.),
    Wc=np.random.randn(Z, H) / np.sqrt(Z / 2.),
    Wo=np.random.randn(Z, H) / np.sqrt(Z / 2.),
    Wy=np.random.randn(H, D) / np.sqrt(D / 2.),
    bf=np.zeros((1, H)),
    bi=np.zeros((1, H)),
    bc=np.zeros((1, H)),
    bo=np.zeros((1, H)),
    by=np.zeros((1, D))
)
```

My model:

```
# RNN class
class RNN:

    def __init__(self, n, d, RL, LR):
        """Pass input size (n), number of memory cells (d), recurrence length (RL), and learning rate (LR)"""
        self.n, self.d, self.z, z = n, d, n + d, n + d
        self.d = d
        self.z, z = n + d, n + d
        self.RL = RL
        self.LR = LR

        self.x = []

        self.Cells = [Cell(n, d, self)]

        self.Wi, self.Wf, self.Wo, self.Wc, self.Wy = randn(z, d) / sqrt(z / 2), randn(z, d) / sqrt(z / 2), randn(z, d) / sqrt(z / 2), randn(z, d) / sqrt(z / 2), randn(d, n) / sqrt(d / 2)
        self.bi, self.bf, self.bo, self.bc, self.by = randn(d, 1), randn(d, 1), randn(d, 1), randn(d, 1), randn(n, 1)
        self.dWi, self.dWf, self.dWo, self.dWc, self.dWy = zeros((z, d)), zeros((z, d)), zeros((z, d)), zeros((z, d)), zeros((d, n))
        self.dbi, self.dbf, self.dbo, self.dbc, self.dby = zeros((d, 1)), zeros((d, 1)), zeros((d, 1)), zeros((d, 1)), zeros((n, 1))
```

My cell:

```
class Cell:

def __init__(self, n, d, rnn):
    """Pass the input size (n) and memory cell size (d), create hidden state of size d, pass rnn (self)"""
    self.n, self.d, self.h, self.z, z = n, d, zeros((d, 1)), n + d, n + d
    self.rnn = rnn
```

Their feedforward:

```
def lstm_forward(X, state):
    m = model
    Wf, Wi, Wc, Wo, Wy = m['Wf'], m['Wi'], m['Wc'], m['Wo'], m['Wy']
    bf, bi, bc, bo, by = m['bf'], m['bi'], m['bc'], m['bo'], m['by']

    h_old, c_old = state

    # One-hot encode
    X_one_hot = np.zeros(D)
    X_one_hot[X] = 1.
    X_one_hot = X_one_hot.reshape(1, -1)

    # Concatenate old state with current input
    X = np.column_stack((h_old, X_one_hot))

    hf = sigmoid(X @ Wf + bf)
    hi = sigmoid(X @ Wi + bi)
    ho = sigmoid(X @ Wo + bo)
    hc = tanh(X @ Wc + bc)

    c = hf * c_old + hi * hc
    h = ho * tanh(c)

    y = h @ Wy + by
    prob = softmax(y)

    state = (h, c) # Cache the states of current h & c for next iter
    cache = ... # Add all intermediate variables to this cache

    return prob, state, cache
```

My feedforward:

```
def feedforward(self, x, c_, h_):
    """Pass an input of size n, the previous hidden state(ht), and the previous cell state(c)"""
    n, d = self.n, self.d
    Wi, Wf, Wo, Wc, Wy = self.rnn.Wi, self.rnn.Wf, self.rnn.Wo, self.rnn.Wc, self.rnn.Wy
    bi, bf, bo, bc, by = self.rnn.bi, self.rnn.bf, self.rnn.bo, self.rnn.bc, self.rnn.by

    index = x       # one hot encoding
    x = zeros((n, 1))
    x[index] = 1
    g = concat((x, h_))         # input g is input x + previous hidden state

    it = sigmoid(dot(Wi.T, g) + bi)     # gate activations
    ft = sigmoid(dot(Wf.T, g) + bf)
    ot = sigmoid(dot(Wo.T, g) + bo)
    ct = tanh(dot(Wc.T, g) + bc)        # non linearity activation
    c = ft * c_ + it * ct       # cell state

    ht = ot * tanh(c)       # squashed hidden state
    yt = dot(Wy.T, ht) + by     # output state
    p = softmax(yt)     # call softmax, get probability

    self.c_, self.h_ = c_, h_
    self.it, self.ft, self.ot, self.ct = it, ft, ot, ct
    self.c, self.ht, self.yt, self.p, self.g = c, ht, yt, p, g

    return ht, c
```

Their backprop:

```
def lstm_backward(prob, y_train, d_next, cache):
    # Unpack the cache variable to get the intermediate variables used in forward step
    ... = cache
    dh_next, dc_next = d_next

    # Softmax loss gradient
    dy = prob.copy()
    dy[1, y_train] -= 1.

    # Hidden to output gradient
    dWy = h.T @ dy
    dby = dy
    # Note we're adding dh_next here
    dh = dy @ Wy.T + dh_next

    # Gradient for ho in h = ho * tanh(c)
    dho = tanh(c) * dh
    dho = dsigmoid(ho) * dho

    # Gradient for c in h = ho * tanh(c), note we're adding dc_next here
    dc = ho * dh * dtanh(c)
    dc = dc + dc_next

    # Gradient for hf in c = hf * c_old + hi * hc
    dhf = c_old * dc
    dhf = dsigmoid(hf) * dhf

    # Gradient for hi in c = hf * c_old + hi * hc
    dhi = hc * dc
    dhi = dsigmoid(hi) * dhi

    # Gradient for hc in c = hf * c_old + hi * hc
    dhc = hi * dc
    dhc = dtanh(hc) * dhc

    # Gate gradients, just a normal fully connected layer gradient
    dWf = X.T @ dhf
    dbf = dhf
    dXf = dhf @ Wf.T

    dWi = X.T @ dhi
    dbi = dhi
    dXi = dhi @ Wi.T

    dWo = X.T @ dho
    dbo = dho
    dXo = dho @ Wo.T

    dWc = X.T @ dhc
    dbc = dhc
    dXc = dhc @ Wc.T

    # As X was used in multiple gates, the gradient must be accumulated here
    dX = dXo + dXc + dXi + dXf
    # Split the concatenated X, so that we get our gradient of h_old
    dh_next = dX[:, :H]
    # Gradient for c_old in c = hf * c_old + hi * hc
    dc_next = hf * dc

    grad = dict(Wf=dWf, Wi=dWi, Wc=dWc, Wo=dWo, Wy=dWy, bf=dbf, bi=dbi, bc=dbc, bo=dbo, by=dby)
    state = (dh_next, dc_next)

    return grad, state
```

My backprop:

```
def backpropagate(self, y, ht1, ct1):

    n, d = self.n, self.d
    Wi, Wf, Wo, Wc, Wy = self.rnn.Wi, self.rnn.Wf, self.rnn.Wo, self.rnn.Wc, self.rnn.Wy
    dWi, dWf, dWo, dWc, dWy = self.rnn.dWi, self.rnn.dWf, self.rnn.dWo, self.rnn.dWc, self.rnn.dWy
    dbi, dbf, dbo, dbc, dby = self.rnn.dbi, self.rnn.dbf, self.rnn.dbo, self.rnn.dbc, self.rnn.dby
    c_, h_ = self.c_, self.h_
    it, ft, ot, ct = self.it, self.ft, self.ot, self.ct
    c, ht, yt, p = self.c, self.ht, self.yt, self.p
    g = self.g

    dy = copy(p)
    dy[y] -= 1

    loss = cross_ent(p, y)

    dh = dot(Wy, dy) + ht1
    dh = clip(dh, -6, 6)

    do = tanh(c) * dh
    do = dsigmoid(ot) * do

    dc = ot * dh * dtanh(c)
    dc = dc + ct1
    dc = clip(dc, -6, 6)

    df = c_ * dc
    df = dsigmoid(ft) * df

    di = ct * dc
    di = dsigmoid(it) * di

    dct = it * dc
    dct = dtanh(ct) * dct

    dWf += dot(g, df.T)
    dWi += dot(g, di.T)
    dWo += dot(g, do.T)
    dWc += dot(g, dc.T)
    dWy += dot(ht, dy.T)

    dbf += df
    dbi += di
    dbo += do
    dbc += dc
    dby += dy

    dxi = dot(Wi, di)
    dxf = dot(Wf, df)
    dxo = dot(Wo, do)
    dxc = dot(Wc, dct)

    dx = dxf + dxi + dxo + dxc

    dht1 = dx[n:]
    dct1 = ft * dc

    return loss, dht1, dct1
```

Their training step:

```
def train_step(X_train, y_train, state):
    probs = []
    caches = []
    loss = 0.
    h, c = state

    # Forward Step

    for x, y_true in zip(X_train, y_train):
        prob, state, cache = lstm_forward(x, state, train=True)
        loss += cross_entropy(prob, y_true)

        # Store forward step result to be used in backward step
        probs.append(prob)
        caches.append(cache)

    # The loss is the average cross entropy
    loss /= X_train.shape[0]

    # Backward Step

    # Gradient for dh_next and dc_next is zero for the last timestep
    d_next = (np.zeros_like(h), np.zeros_like(c))
    grads = {k: np.zeros_like(v) for k, v in model.items()}

    # Go backward from the last timestep to the first
    for prob, y_true, cache in reversed(list(zip(probs, y_train, caches))):
        grad, d_next = lstm_backward(prob, y_true, d_next, cache)

        # Accumulate gradients from all timesteps
        for k in grads.keys():
            grads[k] += grad[k]

    return grads, loss, state
```

My training step:

```
def FeedForward(self, inputs, ht_, ct_):

    n, d, rl, Cells = self.n, self.d, self.RL, self.Cells

    while len(Cells) < rl:
        Cells.append(Cell(n, d, self))

    for cell, x in zip(Cells, range(len(inputs))):
        ht_, ct_ = cell.feedforward(x, ht_, ct_)

    return ht_, ct_



def BPTT(self, outputs, ht1, ct1):

    n, d, z, rl = self.n, self.d, self.n + self.d, self.RL
    Cells = self.Cells

    avg_loss = 0

    for i in reversed(range(rl)):
        loss, ht1, ct1 = Cells[i].backpropagate(outputs[i], ht1, ct1)
        avg_loss += loss

    avg_loss /= rl

    return avg_loss, ht1, ct1


def train(self, inputs, outputs):

    n, d, z, rl = self.n, self.d, self.n + self.d, self.RL
    index = 0
    LR = 0.1
    loss = 0

    ht_, ct_ = zeros((d, 1)), zeros((d, 1))
    ht1, ct1 = zeros((d, 1)), zeros((d, 1))

    while index < len(outputs):
        xlist = inputs[index:index + rl]
        ylist = outputs[index:index + rl]
        ht_, ct_ = self.FeedForward(xlist, ht_, ct_)
        loss, ht1, ct1 = self.BPTT(ylist, ht1, ct1)
        #print(loss)
        self.update(LR)
        index += rl

def update(self, LR):

    n, d, z = self.n, self.d, self.n + self.d

    self.Wi -= LR * self.dWi
    self.Wf -= LR * self.dWf
    self.Wo -= LR * self.dWo
    self.Wc -= LR * self.dWc
    self.Wy -= LR * self.dWy
    self.bi -= LR * self.dbi
    self.bf -= LR * self.dbf
    self.bo -= LR * self.dbo
    self.bc -= LR * self.dbc
    self.by -= LR * self.dby

    self.dWi, self.dWf, self.dWo, self.dWc, self.dWy = zeros((z, d)), zeros((z, d)), zeros((z, d)), zeros((z, d)), zeros((d, n))
    self.dbi, self.dbf, self.dbo, self.dbc, self.dby = zeros((d, 1)), zeros((d, 1)), zeros((d, 1)), zeros((d, 1)), zeros((n, 1))
```

My code in totality:

```
# Import logistic function that doesn't explode outside a 64 bit float
from scipy.special import expit as sigmoid
from numpy import zeros, zeros_like, tanh, exp, sum, dot, sqrt, log, argmax, concatenate as concat, copy
from numpy.random import randn


# derivative of sigmoid function
def dsigmoid(z):
    return sigmoid(z) * (1 - sigmoid(z))

# derivative of hyperbolic tangent
def dtanh(z):
    return 1 - tanh(z) ** 2

# probability function
def softmax(z):
    return exp(z) / sum(exp(z))

# cross entropy loss
def cross_ent(p, y):
    return -log(p[y])


# RNN class
class RNN:
def __init__(self, n, d, RL, LR):
    """Pass input size (n), number of memory cells (d), recurrence length (RL), and learning rate (LR)"""
    self.n, self.d, self.z, z = n, d, n + d, n + d
    self.d = d
    self.z, z = n + d, n + d
    self.RL = RL
    self.LR = LR

    self.x = []

    self.Cells = [Cell(n, d, self)]

    self.Wi, self.Wf, self.Wo, self.Wc, self.Wy = randn(z, d) / sqrt(z / 2), randn(z, d) / sqrt(z / 2), randn(z, d) / sqrt(z / 2), randn(z, d) / sqrt(z / 2), randn(d, n) / sqrt(d / 2)
    self.bi, self.bf, self.bo, self.bc, self.by = randn(d, 1), randn(d, 1), randn(d, 1), randn(d, 1), randn(n, 1)
    self.dWi, self.dWf, self.dWo, self.dWc, self.dWy = zeros((z, d)), zeros((z, d)), zeros((z, d)), zeros((z, d)), zeros((d, n))
    self.dbi, self.dbf, self.dbo, self.dbc, self.dby = zeros((d, 1)), zeros((d, 1)), zeros((d, 1)), zeros((d, 1)), zeros((n, 1))

def FeedForward(self, inputs, ht_, ct_):

    n, d, rl, Cells = self.n, self.d, self.RL, self.Cells

    while len(Cells) < rl:
        Cells.append(Cell(n, d, self))

    for cell, x in zip(Cells, range(len(inputs))):
        ht_, ct_ = cell.feedforward(x, ht_, ct_)

    return ht_, ct_



def BPTT(self, outputs, ht1, ct1):

    n, d, z, rl = self.n, self.d, self.n + self.d, self.RL
    Cells = self.Cells

    avg_loss = 0

    for i in reversed(range(rl)):
        loss, ht1, ct1 = Cells[i].backpropagate(outputs[i], ht1, ct1)
        avg_loss += loss

    avg_loss /= rl

    return avg_loss, ht1, ct1


def train(self, inputs, outputs):

    n, d, z, rl = self.n, self.d, self.n + self.d, self.RL
    index = 0
    LR = 0.1
    loss = 0

    ht_, ct_ = zeros((d, 1)), zeros((d, 1))
    ht1, ct1 = zeros((d, 1)), zeros((d, 1))

    while index < len(outputs):
        xlist = inputs[index:index + rl]
        ylist = outputs[index:index + rl]
        ht_, ct_ = self.FeedForward(xlist, ht_, ct_)
        loss, ht1, ct1 = self.BPTT(ylist, ht1, ct1)
        #print(loss)
        self.update(LR)
        index += rl

def update(self, LR):

    n, d, z = self.n, self.d, self.n + self.d

    self.Wi -= LR * self.dWi
    self.Wf -= LR * self.dWf
    self.Wo -= LR * self.dWo
    self.Wc -= LR * self.dWc
    self.Wy -= LR * self.dWy
    self.bi -= LR * self.dbi
    self.bf -= LR * self.dbf
    self.bo -= LR * self.dbo
    self.bc -= LR * self.dbc
    self.by -= LR * self.dby

    self.dWi, self.dWf, self.dWo, self.dWc, self.dWy = zeros((z, d)), zeros((z, d)), zeros((z, d)), zeros((z, d)), zeros((d, n))
    self.dbi, self.dbf, self.dbo, self.dbc, self.dby = zeros((d, 1)), zeros((d, 1)), zeros((d, 1)), zeros((d, 1)), zeros((n, 1))
```

class Cell:

```
def __init__(self, n, d, rnn):
    """Pass the input size (n) and memory cell size (d), create hidden state of size d, pass rnn (self)"""
    self.n, self.d, self.h, self.z, z = n, d, zeros((d, 1)), n + d, n + d
    self.rnn = rnn


def feedforward(self, x, c_, h_):
    """Pass an input of size n, the previous hidden state(ht), and the previous cell state(c)"""
    n, d = self.n, self.d
    Wi, Wf, Wo, Wc, Wy = self.rnn.Wi, self.rnn.Wf, self.rnn.Wo, self.rnn.Wc, self.rnn.Wy
    bi, bf, bo, bc, by = self.rnn.bi, self.rnn.bf, self.rnn.bo, self.rnn.bc, self.rnn.by

    index = x       # one hot encoding
    x = zeros((n, 1))
    x[index] = 1
    g = concat((x, h_))         # input g is input x + previous hidden state

    it = sigmoid(dot(Wi.T, g) + bi)     # gate activations
    ft = sigmoid(dot(Wf.T, g) + bf)
    ot = sigmoid(dot(Wo.T, g) + bo)
    ct = tanh(dot(Wc.T, g) + bc)        # non linearity activation
    c = ft * c_ + it * ct       # cell state

    ht = ot * tanh(c)       # squashed hidden state
    yt = dot(Wy.T, ht) + by     # output state
    p = softmax(yt)     # call softmax, get probability

    self.c_, self.h_ = c_, h_
    self.it, self.ft, self.ot, self.ct = it, ft, ot, ct
    self.c, self.ht, self.yt, self.p, self.g = c, ht, yt, p, g

    return ht, c


def backpropagate(self, y, ht1, ct1):

    n, d = self.n, self.d
    Wi, Wf, Wo, Wc, Wy = self.rnn.Wi, self.rnn.Wf, self.rnn.Wo, self.rnn.Wc, self.rnn.Wy
    dWi, dWf, dWo, dWc, dWy = self.rnn.dWi, self.rnn.dWf, self.rnn.dWo, self.rnn.dWc, self.rnn.dWy
    dbi, dbf, dbo, dbc, dby = self.rnn.dbi, self.rnn.dbf, self.rnn.dbo, self.rnn.dbc, self.rnn.dby
    c_, h_ = self.c_, self.h_
    it, ft, ot, ct = self.it, self.ft, self.ot, self.ct
    c, ht, yt, p = self.c, self.ht, self.yt, self.p
    g = self.g

    dy = copy(p)
    dy[y] -= 1

    loss = cross_ent(p, y)

    dh = dot(Wy, dy) + ht1
    dh = clip(dh, -6, 6)

    do = tanh(c) * dh
    do = dsigmoid(ot) * do

    dc = ot * dh * dtanh(c)
    dc = dc + ct1
    dc = clip(dc, -6, 6)

    df = c_ * dc
    df = dsigmoid(ft) * df

    di = ct * dc
    di = dsigmoid(it) * di

    dct = it * dc
    dct = dtanh(ct) * dct

    dWf += dot(g, df.T)
    dWi += dot(g, di.T)
    dWo += dot(g, do.T)
    dWc += dot(g, dc.T)
    dWy += dot(ht, dy.T)

    dbf += df
    dbi += di
    dbo += do
    dbc += dc
    dby += dy

    dxi = dot(Wi, di)
    dxf = dot(Wf, df)
    dxo = dot(Wo, do)
    dxc = dot(Wc, dct)

    dx = dxf + dxi + dxo + dxc

    dht1 = dx[n:]
    dct1 = ft * dc

    return loss, dht1, dct1

file = open("trumptweets.txt", 'r', encoding='utf8').read()

text = list(file)

alphabet = list(set(text))

n = (len(alphabet))
d = 100

encode = {ch:i for i,ch in enumerate(alphabet)}
decode = {i:ch for i,ch in enumerate(alphabet)}

inputs = [encode[ch] for ch in text]
outputs = [inputs[i + 1] for i in range(len(inputs)-1)]


RNN = LSTM.RNN(n, d, 100, 0.1)

RNN.train(inputs, outputs)
```

The loss increases somewhat as the network trains. I'm not sure what the bug is because I can't find any definitive sources on how a LSTM works. I've implemented like 5 incomplete, broken, or incorrect guides at this point.

For anyone who doesn't want to read through my code I am following the following algorithm:

1. Encode characters as integers
2. Initialize starting hidden state and cell state.
3. Add a recurrence length number of cells to a list.
4. For recurrence length inputs encode each as a one hot vector.
5. Concatenate old hidden state with one hot.
6. Feed forward, compute recurrence length gates and activations.
7. Save cell states, output, hidden state, and probabilities.
8. Initialize next hidden and cell state.
9. Pass labels and states to BPTT
10. Backpropagate each cell starting at the end, accumulate gradient.
11. Update weights.
12. Move inputs/outputs forward by recurrence length steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was missing was the correct update rule. The guide I mostly followed used ADAM so I implemented it from the research paper and it works.

```
def train(self, inputs, outputs):

    n, d, z, rl = self.n, self.d, self.n + self.d, self.RL
    index, t, converged = 0, 0, False
    a, b1, b2, e = 0.001, 0.9, 0.999, 1e-8

    mWi, mWf, mWo, mWc, mWy = zeros_like((self.Wi)), zeros_like((self.Wf)), zeros_like((self.Wo)), zeros_like((self.Wc)), zeros_like((self.Wy))
    mbi, mbf, mbo, mbc, mby = zeros_like((self.bi)), zeros_like((self.bf)), zeros_like((self.bo)), zeros_like((self.bc)), zeros_like((self.by))

    vWi, vWf, vWo, vWc, vWy = zeros_like((self.Wi)), zeros_like((self.Wf)), zeros_like((self.Wo)), zeros_like((self.Wc)), zeros_like((self.Wy))
    vbi, vbf, vbo, vbc, vby = zeros_like((self.bi)), zeros_like((self.bf)), zeros_like((self.bo)), zeros_like((self.bc)), zeros_like((self.by))

    ht_, ct_ = zeros((d, 1)), zeros((d, 1))
    ht1, ct1 = zeros((d, 1)), zeros((d, 1))

    while not converged:

        t += 1
        xlist = inputs[index:index + rl]
        ylist = outputs[index:index + rl]
        ht_, ct_ = self.FeedForward(xlist, ht_, ct_)
        loss, ht1, ct1 = self.BPTT(ylist, ht1, ct1)
        print(loss)

        dWi, dWf, dWo, dWc, dWy = self.dWi, self.dWf, self.dWo, self.dWc, self.dWy
        dbi, dbf, dbo, dbc, dby = self.dbi, self.dbf, self.dbo, self.dbc, self.dby

        mWi = b1 * mWi + (1 - b1) * dWi
        mWf = b1 * mWf + (1 - b1) * dWf
        mWo = b1 * mWo + (1 - b1) * dWo
        mWc = b1 * mWc + (1 - b1) * dWc
        mWy = b1 * mWy + (1 - b1) * dWy
        mbi = b1 * mbi + (1 - b1) * dbi
        mbf = b1 * mbf + (1 - b1) * dbf
        mbo = b1 * mbo + (1 - b1) * dbo
        mbc = b1 * mbc + (1 - b1) * dbc
        mby = b1 * mby + (1 - b1) * dby

        vWi = b2 * vWi + (1 - b2) * dWi**2
        vWf = b2 * vWf + (1 - b2) * dWf**2
        vWo = b2 * vWo + (1 - b2) * dWo**2
        vWc = b2 * vWc + (1 - b2) * dWc**2
        vWy = b2 * vWy + (1 - b2) * dWy**2
        vbi = b2 * vbi + (1 - b2) * dbi**2
        vbf = b2 * vbf + (1 - b2) * dbf**2
        vbo = b2 * vbo + (1 - b2) * dbo**2
        vbc = b2 * vbc + (1 - b2) * dbc**2
        vby = b2 * vby + (1 - b2) * dby**2

        mWi_ = mWi / (1 - b1**t)
        mWf_ = mWf / (1 - b1**t)
        mWo_ = mWo / (1 - b1**t)
        mWc_ = mWc / (1 - b1**t)
        mWy_ = mWy / (1 - b1**t)
        mbi_ = mbi / (1 - b1**t)
        mbf_ = mbf / (1 - b1**t)
        mbo_ = mbo / (1 - b1**t)
        mbc_ = mbc / (1 - b1**t)
        mby_ = mby / (1 - b1**t)

        vWi_ = vWi / (1 - b2**t)
        vWf_ = vWf / (1 - b2**t)
        vWo_ = vWo / (1 - b2**t)
        vWc_ = vWc / (1 - b2**t)
        vWy_ = vWy / (1 - b2**t)
        vbi_ = vbi / (1 - b2**t)
        vbf_ = vbf / (1 - b2**t)
        vbo_ = vbo / (1 - b2**t)
        vbc_ = vbc / (1 - b2**t)
        vby_ = vby / (1 - b2**t)

        self.Wi = self.Wi - a * mWi_ / (sqrt(vWi_) + e)
        self.Wf = self.Wf - a * mWf_ / (sqrt(vWf_) + e)
        self.Wo = self.Wo - a * mWo_ / (sqrt(vWo_) + e)
        self.Wc = self.Wc - a * mWc_ / (sqrt(vWc_) + e)
        self.Wy = self.Wy - a * mWy_ / (sqrt(vWy_) + e)
        self.bi = self.bi - a * mbi_ / (sqrt(vbi_) + e)
        self.bf = self.bf - a * mbf_ / (sqrt(vbf_) + e)
        self.bo = self.bo - a * mbo_ / (sqrt(vbo_) + e)
        self.bc = self.bc - a * mbc_ / (sqrt(vbc_) + e)
        self.by = self.by - a * mby_ / (sqrt(vby_) + e)

        self.dWi, self.dWf, self.dWo, self.dWc, self.dWy = zeros((z, d)), zeros((z, d)), zeros((z, d)), zeros((z, d)), zeros((d, n))
        self.dbi, self.dbf, self.dbo, self.dbc, self.dby = zeros((d, 1)), zeros((d, 1)), zeros((d, 1)), zeros((d, 1)), zeros((n, 1))

        index += rl
        if index >= len(outputs): index = 0
```

Comment: @Grant_Swalwell Hi, I'm having a similar problem to you and I was just wondering if it would be possible to post your full working code for the lstm so I can see where it deviates from my own.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, my code is here https://github.com/grantSwalwell/Machine-Learning/blob/master/Long%20Short%20Term%20Memory/LSTM.py
but it is still missing something, the loss only goes down by about 10% then flatlines, not sure why